# How to get the next element from an array for a given subarray

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array `["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]` and also an `subarray` `["a", "b", "c"]` . Now the next element in the main array to `subarray` is `d` . So I want to get the array as `["a", "b", "c", "d"]` .

I know there are so many ways to get this . Like

```
get length of subarray => 3
slice from main array `length of subarray + 1` => _.slice(main_array, 0, 4)
```

Is there any other elegant way to do this , I am preferably looking for solution using `lodash`.

Comment: If you know for a fact that `subarray` starts at the start of the array (i.e. it’s a prefix), then I don’t think you’re going to get much simpler than the solution you described (which seems perfectly clean). You don’t need Lodash to slice, either: `main_array.slice(0, subarray.length + 1)`

Comment: @Ry- yes `subarray` will be always a prefix. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: `slice` (Lodash or plain JS) is pretty elegant. Lodash offers `take` which basically just saves you passing the zero: `_.take(main_array, subarray.length + 1)`. But I wouldn't use Lodash *just* for that. If you already have Lodash for other stuff in your project, then go ahead and use it but don't add it just for this task.

Comment: @VLAZ yes we are using `lodash` extensively .

Comment: My dude @VLAZ closed the question minutes before I could answer with a use of the **spread operator**: `[...subarray, main_array[subarray.length]]`
No function calls, no number operations.